# With Ubuntu livepatch and unattended-upgrades is it possible to run a server fully patched without restarting the server or services or logging in?

Tags: ubuntu, update, ubuntu-16.04, uptime, automatic-updates

A few weeks ago Canonical started offering livepatching for kernel updates without needing to reboot the server ( http://insights.ubuntu.com/2016/10/20/live-kernel-patching-from-canonical-now-available-for-ubuntu/ ).

Assume the following scenario: You have a webserver running on Ubuntu 16.04 with livepatch and unattended-upgrades enabled. Will it be possible to let it run for like a year without an server admin logging in and still be secure against known/patched exploits? Will also all other packages be running up to date (like openssl) or will you need to manually restart certain services to have them up to date?

Comment: Single-host uptime is overrated. If you truly need that level of availability, you're shooting yourself in the foot by doing things this way. It's far better to build a horizontally-scalable, programmatically-deployed infrastructure, where any one host can be taken down and re-built ex nihilo without affecting your application. So, while your question may be interesting from a point of curiosity, it's not a good way to run things.

Comment: As a thought experiment: after a year or more of upgrades and patches, how certain are you that services will come up properly upon a cold boot, or even that the server will boot at all?

Comment: @EEAA you are right that the question is mostly out of curiosity and you shouldn't be run a server this way in critical production environment. But I have seen some small companies who installed a server (often by a poorly trained employee or an external person or the nephew of the boss) and then let it run for years unpatched (some of the ones I saw were not updated for 5+ years). So I thought it reduce the security problem and in case it would fail, they would notice it and know they need to do something about it.

Comment: Automated processes are never a substitute for competent management of any software system. They can help alleviate some pain points, but relying on them is folly.

Comment: @EEAA Interestingly most updates went very flawless (they mostly didn't have complex setup, just basic stuff) except for the one where I tried to upgrade from 10.04 to 16.04 where the upgrade process broke and I then decided to just rebuild the server from new.

Comment: Most do, until they don't. At which point they're down until someone can manually patch things back together. Not a good place to be...

Comment: @EEAA yes, I have come across too many places who handled it this way and they asked me to "take a glance at their servers" in exchange for a coffee or other amenities and I wouldn't professionally recommend anyone to have a non-managed internet facing server running but the reality looks different. That's why the question came into my mind and for rebuilding I expect them to have a backup anyway.